# Select subquery not working in Intellij idea

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, pgadmin-4

I have the following query (Assume that the tables are present):

```
select tmp.ship_country 
from (
  select o.ship_country, count (*) c 
  from orders o 
  group by o.ship_country 
  order by c desc limit 1
) tmp;
```

When I attempt to run this via `IntelliJ Idea Database Browser`, I get following error:

> Error executing SELECT statement: ERROR: subquery in FROM must have
>   alias. HINT: For example, `FROM (SELECT...) [AS] foo`. Position: 30

The same query runs fine when executed from `PGADMIN4`. Below are the associated screenshots:

[image: When executed from IntelliJ idea]

[image: Error Message In IntelliJ]

[image: Query Executed from PgAdmin 4]

[image: Correct Result in PgAdmin4]

Am I missing something or is this a bug in `Idea`? I am using IntelliJ Idea 2019.3 (CE).

[image: CE having Database Navigator]

Comment: Side note: You don't need that derived table here. Just remove the `count()` from the list of columns and order by it instead of the alias.

Comment: Does CE have data base support? Same Query works in Ultimate.

Comment: @Peter There is a Database Navigator that allows us to write queries and execute them.

Comment: @stickybit Thanks for the suggestion. Since I am very new to SQL queries, the queries might not be optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Database Navigator Plugin available for IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition isn't provided by JetBrains (anymore) and has nothing to do with the DataGrip extension or IDE that is available with the Ultimate Edition.

The error you are facing is a bug in the https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator/ plugin.

I could reproduce that bug with current release `3.2.0564`.

Created issue: https://database-navigator.atlassian.net/browse/DBNB-33